# How to remove Powerlevel9k from terminal?

Tags: terminal, zsh

iMac/macOS Catalina 10.15.4

I installed the Powerlevel9k theme for zsh in iTerm2, didn't like it and cannot get rid of it.

I have edited the `.zshrc` file back to `robbyrussell`, but that has no effect. I actually uninstalled iTerm2 and when I opened terminal, Powerlevel9k was there too. I stopped it running with `prompt_powerlevel9k_teardown`, but it must still be lurking somewhere.

The repo, https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k, gives no directions for removing Powerlevel9k, so I am not tempted to try Powerlevel10k.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: FYI: Powerlevel10k has uninstall instructions: https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-uninstall-powerlevel10k.

Answer (score 3):

People coming here in **2022**, follow their official documentation to uninstall https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#how-do-i-uninstall-powerlevel10k **will take not more than a minute**.

And with this line in the installation process, makes it so easy **The command to delete them depends on which installation method you'd chosen. Refer to the installation instructions if you need a reminder.**

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is no "install" for powerlevel9k - it's just a directory with the code in it. To "uninstall" it, simply delete the directory where you downloaded the code.

Comment: Sorry to see this @maxthestranger, I don't know why someone would give -1 here. This is how it is. Here's their official documentation to uninstall https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#how-do-i-uninstall-powerlevel10k.

Answer (score 1):

When downloaded from Github source and manually changed, please comment out `ZSH_THEME` env var:

```
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
# ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove powerlevel9 resolved:
I found these lines at the bottom of the .zshrc file. I commented them out which solved the problem so now I could just delete them.

```
# export NVM_DIR="/Users/EJR/.nvm"
# [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
#source /usr/local/opt/powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme
```

Comment: I should have realized that this is the powerlevel9k file to remove:  /usr/local/opt/powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme.